# How to train LM on more data?

Tags: returnn

I wang to train a new lm for more data using returnn. But I don't know the exactly form for tain and dev,e.g.

```
/work/asr3/irie/data/librispeech/lm_bpe/librispeech-lm-norm.bpe.txt.gz
```

Second,I wanner why the train_num_seqs equals `40418260`, while the librispeech trainig dataset has only `281241`sentences. Waiting for your answering

Answer (score 0):

You can download the LM model [here](https://github.com/rwth-i6/returnn-experiments/tree/master/2018-asr-attention/librispeech/lm).

The LM train data can be downloaded from the [official page](http://www.openslr.org/11/).
It might need some post processing to prepare that file librispeech-lm-norm.bpe.txt.gz but it should be straightforward.

The `cf` function uses [some tool of us](https://github.com/rwth-i6/cache-manager), but you can ignore it. Just remove it.

Also, see the discussion in the GitHub issue which you posted [here](https://github.com/rwth-i6/returnn-experiments/issues/21).